# Como mudar o delimitador do array Php obtido via POST, substituindo a vírgula?

Tags: php, array

Recebo um array *via POST* que é gerado de um campo `name="Referencia[]"` do formulário, o problema é que nesse array tem informações com vírgula.

Exemplo: 2,7 cm, 3,1 cm.

Eu insiro no banco de dados separado pelas vírgulas para ser recuperado utilizando elas, mas neste caso separa errado.

Gostaria de trocar a virgula por '__' pra usar o *implode* gerando `2,7 cm__3,1 cm` e não delimitando por vírgula neste caso.

Resultado esperado:

```
$MyArray = explode("__", array_filter( $_POST['Referencia'] ) );


echo $MyArray; // 2,7 cm__3,1
```

*OBSERVAÇÃO: Atualmente os dados estão inseridos neste formato* '**7,7 cm,8,8 cm,9,8 cm**' *, a solução pode ser feita no formulário ou depois do envio, mas o interessante seria inserir no banco de dados já formatado assim:* '**7,7 cm__8,8 cm__9,8 cm**'

Comment: Só lamento o "ser"  não entender a pergunta e negativar !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realmente fazer o que está pedindo, você pode utilizar a função [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) e localizar os devidos valores com uma expressão regular:

```
$reference = "2,7 cm, 3,1 cm, 20,0 dm, 0,89 m, 0,0001 km";

if (preg_match_all("/[0-9]+\,[0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]+/", $reference, $matches))
{
  print_r($matches);
}
```

A saída será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2,7 cm
            [1] => 3,1 cm
            [2] => 20,0 dm
            [3] => 0,89 m
            [4] => 0,0001 km
        )

)
```

Então bastaria fazer: `implode("__", $matches[0])` para ter:

```
2,7 cm__3,1 cm__20,0 dm__0,89 m__0,0001 km
```

> Perceba que desta forma o programa é capaz de lidar, também, com diferentes unidades.

Comment: Essa expressão salvou, obrigado @Anderson Carlos Woss

Answer (score 0):

Se os dados já estão nesse padrão `2,7 cm, 3,1 cm` e tem certeza de que esse padrão se manterá sempre dessa forma, então poderia apenas usar `,` (vírgula e espaço) como delimitador, assim não precisaria modificar nada no processo que envia do formulário.

No `explode()` ficaria algo assim

```
$MyArray = explode(", ", array_filter( $_POST['Referencia'] ) );
```

O array será

```
array(
    2,7 cm,
    3,1 cm
)
```

Isso parece ser o jeito menos invasivo e limpo.

Não está claro onde deseja modificar, se é no formulário antes do envio ou os dois lados. Por fim, optei por mostrar uma solução que seja a mais simples possível.